# added files to module: use drush to upgrade to a new version of this module will added files be deleted?

Tags: drush

A co-worker has added a couple of .css files to the quicktabs 3rd party module.  What will happen if you use drush to upgrade to a new version of this module.
Will these added files be deleted or kept as-is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the css files are stored in the quicktabs module directory, yes they will be lost upon upgrade.

Comment: To be honest, I experienced the opposite. I'm confused now. Of course assuming they MAY be deleted is always wise.

Comment: They should always be deleted. Please post a bug report in the issue queue with steps to reproduce and the version you are using if you experience anything else.

Comment: I no longer work on that site, if I'll experience it again I'll be sure to report it. My rough guess is that they was uploaded with template developer uid and gid and thus was readonly for uid we ran drush and website on.